# DB2 9.7 Distinct rows returned

Tags: db2, distinct

I have been researching through the posted material on the site and can't figure if it is `GROUP BY` or `PARTITION BY` and I can't seem to get the answer I want.

What I have is an enormous amount of `TAG` data and what I need is to retrieve a history of  locations that it was seen at i.e. show me the last time it was seen at a particular location.

I have added a small subset of the data.

What I would want to see is by date Order being newest first so I would expect to see ROW 01 as the first in location ...004 and then next entry would be ROW 209 as it it the latest entry for ...50 and then ROW 216 ..004 again so everytime there is a change.

Can this be done with a SQL Statement

Thanks for any help you can offer

```
ROW    TAG    DATE
001    004    2012-10-19 10:20
002    004    2012-10-19 10:10
003    004    2012-10-19 10:00
209    050    2012-10-19 08:50
210    050    2012-10-19 08:40
211    050    2012-10-19 08:30
216    004    2012-10-19 07:30
217    004    2012-10-19 02:20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it can be done:

```
with last_records_tagged as (
    select 
        row, 
        tag, 
        date,
        case when lead(tag) over (partition by tag order by date asc) is null 
            then 1 
            else 0
        end as last
        from your_table
)
select * from last_records_tagged where last = 1
```

(I ordered ascending by date because it makes more sense to me).

Basically, any time the next record, ordered by date, has a different tag, you know you are at the last record of that group.